# Android app: Html formatting "[]" when importing text from database

Tags: android, html

When I in my android application import text from my database it returns text with a square symbol. The text in the database is pasted from a webpage so I belive it is som html formatting, [ENTER] etc.
Is it possible to make the textview understand the formatting and use it as it is intended to look in a webbrowser. I am not interested in changing the view if it can be avoided, just to make the textstring use the formatting to make \nl etc.

Any one know how it can be done.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before setting the text in the `TextView` you can use the `Html.fromHtml` method on the text, this will format the text appropriately.

Comment: Hi again. The only thing it did to my code after testing it more is to remove the square format tag (dont know the name of the symbol and it is not represented on my keyboard, similar to []).

Comment: To make it really easy, what I want to do is to change the tags to "\n" to break the text to a new line. Is there any way to do that manually?